# printing fibonacci number series without using loops

Tags: java, algorithm, fibonacci

Is there a hack to print the first n fibonacci numbers without calling a loop

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    System.out.println(computeF(n));
```

from the main program?

```
public static int computeF(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return computeF(n-1)+computeF(n-2); 
    }

}
```

There might be a way to print the intermediate values in recursion which will print the fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  Any recusive algo can be serialized.  This sounds like homework.

Comment: nope it's not homework!!! I was just practicing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Comment: Tail recursion requires that the last statement of the function is calling itself.  But here we have: `return computeF(n-1)+computeF(n-2)`

Comment: @mike, your looking at it from the wrong angle. The Fibonacci sequence is still an iterative sequence and does not need to call itself twice. You just need to include some more information when you do call yourself. `ComputeF(d, n1, n2) => d == 0 ? n1 : ComputeF(d - 1, n2, n2 + n1)`. Then start it with `ComputeF(n, 0, 1)`

Comment: recursion is a form of a loop really

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class Fid   
  {   
    static int n1=0;
    static int n2=1;
    static int nex=0;
    public static  void fb(int n)
 {
   if(n<10)
    {
      if(n==0)
       {
         System.out.print(" "+n);
         n++;
         fb(n);
       }
        else
           if(n==1)
       {
         System.out.print(" "+n);
         n++;
         fb(n);
       }

        else{ 
            nex=n1+n2;
            System.out.print(" "+nex);
            n1=n2;
            n2=nex;
            n++;
            fb(n);                
            }           
      }        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      fb(0);                                          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using recursion:-

```
  class FibonacciRecursion
{
private static int index = 0;
private static int stoppingPoint = 9;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
  int n1 = 0;
  int n2 = 1;

  fibonacciSequence(n1, n2);
}

public static void fibonacciSequence(int n1, int n2)
{
  System.out.println("index: " + index + " -> " + n1);

  // make sure we have set an ending point so this Java recursion
  // doesn't go on forever.
  if (index == stoppingPoint)
    return;

  // make sure we increment our index so we make progress
  // toward the end.
  index++;

  fibonacciSequence(n2, n1+n2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Java program to print Fibonacci Series up to n terms given by user without using loop

import java.util.* ;

public class Fibonacci
{

public static void main(String[] arguments) 
  {

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the no of terms :");
int no_of_terms= s.nextInt(),a=1,b=0,c=0,count=1;
System.out.print("0 ");//printing the first term
fib(no_of_terms,a,b,c,count);}
```

public static void fib(int no_of_terms,int a,int b,int c,int count)
  {

```
//when value of count will be equal to the no of terms given by user the program will terminate

if (count==no_of_terms)
   System.exit(0);
else
{
  count++;
  System.out.print(a+" ");
  c=b;
  b=a;
  a=b+c;//calculating the next term
  fib(no_of_terms,a,b,c,count);//calling the function again with updated value
}
```

}
}

Comment: What's your question? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Edit the markdown in your answer to properly structure your code example.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Fibonacci{
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a no.");
    int n= sc.nextInt(),a=1,b=0,c=0;
    num(n,a,b,c);
  }
  public static void num(int n,int a,int b,int c){
    if(a<=n){
      System.out.println(a);
      c=b;
      b=a;
      a=b+c;
      num(n,a,b,c);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There you go, it is the shortest and simplest program possible

Comment: Add some description to your answer.

Comment: When I enter `93`, I get eleven numbers: how does this answer `Is there a [way] to print the first` *`n`* `Fibonacci numbers without calling a loop`?